# MVC - Manipulate Jquery plug in properties in ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am working with a Jquery time picker from http://labs.perifer.se/timedatepicker/

In the view I have this time picker control.

```
   $("#startTime").timePicker({
        startTime: "09.00", 
        endTime: new Date(0, 0, 0, 19, 0, 0), 
        show24Hours: false,
        separator: '.',
        step: 30
    });
```

If a particular time (say 11:00 AM) is picked previously (and saved in db) that particular option should be disabled and not available for subsequent selections. In a MVC controller, via a service layer, I am getting a 'list' of all previously picked times.

```
    public ActionResult DisableTimes(param1, param2)
    {            
        List<string> listTimes = Webservice(param1,param2);
        //getting previously saved times - above line
        return Json(listTimes, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

I am making an ajax call in a java script function like this.. that passes the parameters to MVC controller and returns back the list of times.

```
       $.ajax({

          "url": "/ControllerName/DisableTimes/",
          "type": "get",
          "dataType": "json",
          "data": { param1: $("#paramval1").val(), param2: $("#paramvalue2").val() },
          "success": function (listTimes) {

              //Code here - use the listTimes values and disable the 
              //appropriate timepicker drop down choices.
               }
           });
```

How can I make use of the list of times "listTimes" I am getting from controller to disable the Jquery Timepicker choices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just be able to remove the li's from available options in the following manner:

```
$(listTimes).each(function() {
    $('.time-picker').find('li:contains("' + this + '")').remove();
});
```

Edit:

It will be a little bit harder if you have multiple time pickers on a page though. You should be able to add the `:first` selector to only get the first time picker.

```
$('.time-picker:first').find('li:contains("' + this + '")').remove();
```

[Live DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ZPfGd/1/)

Answer (score 1):

apparently this datepicker plugin doesn't give you the possibility to remove his behavior.

But I do believe that you could remove the element from the document.

and re-add it again.

using :

http://api.jquery.com/remove/

and

http://api.jquery.com/add/

Or you could have two element for each time, show/hide what you need or using :

http://api.jquery.com/hide/

and

http://api.jquery.com/show/

Answer (score 1):

it doesn't seem that the plugin offers that functionality by default. I would change these lines in the plugin code slightly (the bits where it appends to the list)

```
// Build the list
    for(var i = 0; i < times.length; i++) {
      $tpList.append("<li>" + times[i] + "</li>");
    }
```

to something that adds some identifier to each li:

```
for(var i = 0; i < times.length; i++) {
      $tpList.append("<li class='"+times[i]+'">" + times[i] + "</li>");
    }`
```

just to make selecting those li elements easier then in your success handler, do something like:

```
    "success": function (listTimes) {
         $(listTimes).each(function(i,item){
               $('li.'+item).remove();
         });
        //or may be if you are just getting an array of strings from the webservice then something like this will be enough: $('.'+listTimes.join(',.')).remove();
     }
```

and also put the timepicker plugin call $("#startTime").timePicker inside the ajax success callback so that there is no race condition as the ajax callback will happen after the plugin initialization probably.

Another alternative is just to handle $('#startTime').change and check if the time is not allowed and display an error to the user.